# BlackBerry MapField

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-maps

***problem using  BlackBerry MapField***

This is the code i use for displaying a map:

```
class MapScreen extends FullScreen
{
    public MapScreen() 
    {
        super( FullScreen.DEFAULT_CLOSE | FullScreen.DEFAULT_MENU );
        MapField map = new MapField();
        MapAction action = map.getAction();
        action.setCentreAndZoom(new MapPoint(40, -40), 3);   
        add(map);
    }
}
```

But only map tiles appear in the screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
MapField mMapField;
Coordinates mCoordinates;
mCoordinates = new Coordinates( -25.900461, 28.135085, 0);
mMapField = new MapField();
mMapField.moveTo(mCoordinates);
add(mMapField);
```